# Return value for correct session?

Tags: database, session, asp-classic, session-variables, kdb

I'm working on a project in dead ASP (I know :( )

Anyway it is working with a kdb+ database which is major overkill but not my call.  Therefore to do inserts etc we're having to write special functions so they can be handled.

Anyway we've hit a theoretical problem and I'm a bit unsure how it should be dealt with in this case.

So basically you register a company, when you submit validation will occur and the page will be processed, inserting new values to the appropriate tables.  Now at this stage I want to pull ID's from the tables and use them in the session for further registration screens.  The user will never add a specific ID of course so it needs to be pulled from the database.

But how can this be done?  I'm particularly concerned with 2 user's simultaneously registering, how can I ensure the correct ID is passed back to the correct session?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things you put in the Session(...) collection is only visible to that session (i.e. the session is used only by the browser windows on one computer). The session is identified by a GUID value that is stored in a cookie on the client machine. It is "safe" to store your IDs there (other users won't be able to read them easily) .

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having the ID set at the point of insert, is it possible for you to "grab" an ID value before hand, and then use that value throughout the process?

So:

1. Start the registration.
2. System connects to the database, creates an ID (perhaps from an ID table) and Stores in ASP Session.
3. Company registers.
4. You validate and insert data into DB (including the ID session)

Answer (score 0):

either your id can include date and time - so it will be example - id31032012200312 - but if you still think that 2 people can register at the same type then I would use recordset locks liek the ones here - http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_rs_locktype.asp

To crea ids like above in asp you do - replace(date(),"/","") '    and then same with time with ":"

Thanks